# Running CodeBlocks and VMWare Workstation at the same time on Windows 7 host causes lockup

Tags: windows-7, crash, codeblocks, vmware-workstation

I'm running Windows 7 Pro, SP1 on a Dell Precision M2800 (I know it's out of date).

My VMWare Workstation version is 11.1.4 build 3848939. Right now I'm using it primarily for a VM with Windows 7 and a bunch of (latest) Rockwell/Keyence software.

I'm using CodeBlocks version 16.01 to compile C++. Packages I'm using in my code include various SDL libraries and the standard stuff.

The issue I'm having is repeatable for me:
I start both VMWare and CodeBlocks running on my host machine. I compile and test code in CodeBlocks while I wait for Rockwell to finish compiling/uploading/etc.. After a couple of times compiling and running programs with CodeBlocks, my host OS will lock up for a long time (more than an hour). I haven't waited long enough to see if it ever unlocks on its own.

The work-around I'm using right now is to just not use those programs at the same time. I'm not necessarily looking for a solution, (because I anticipate that everyone will just tell me to update Windows), although solutions are fine. I'm looking for information about the root cause. Anybody have ideas about why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clipped off the C++ tag because this isn't related to C++ code and only loosely related to C++ coding tools.

Comment: @user4581301 Gotcha. Thanks!